# How to add outer colour around this div when it has focus?

Tags: html, css

If you look [here](https://www.access.service.gov.uk/login/signin/creds) and click in the password box it has a yellow focus rectangle:

[image: Focus]

The control in question is a `input` but I want to do it to a `div`. Take this code:

```html
<div class="bbp-template-notice error" role="alert" tabindex="-1">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>ERROR</strong>: Your reply cannot be empty.</li>
        <li><strong>ERROR</strong>: Please solve Captcha correctly.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What CSS styling must I apply to get this outer yellow?

At the moment I have:

```
#bbpress-forums .bbp-template-notice {
    padding: 2px !important;
    border: solid 1px #000 !important;
    background: #708090;
}
```

Which gives this result:

[image: Error Styling]

Any guidance gratefully appreciated.

Comment: If the div has a tab index it should accept a `:focus` selector...I think. Then apply an `outline`

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks. I will try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paulie_D advised, outline property is what you're looking for when the element is focused. If you need to know what options are available for the `outline` property, [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) has great visuals that you can review

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go.

Comment: I wish I could accept BOTH answers with a tick because you BOTH have provided something valuable to me. I am accepting this one because you have indicated I should use the `outline` property and provided direction to the W3 Schools website for forward learning.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code for adding a border on div focus.

```
.bbp-template-notice {
    padding: 2px !important;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #708090;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}


.bbp-template-notice:focus {
    outline: #ff0 solid 4px !important;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could accept BOTH answers with a tick because you BOTH have provided something valuable to me. I accepted the other one but I really appreciate your code. IMHO I feel that your code snippet should be a part of the accepted answer. But I have voted on both of your answers because you were helpful!